# Issues editing ASP.net Razor view files while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, tfs, razor, editing

I am building an MVC3 application using RAZOR in VS 2010. TFS 2010 is being used for source control.

When debugging the application, it is helpful to be able to modify the Razor view files on they fly. If I open a checked-out view file in VS2010 before I start debugging, I can edit this file while I am debugging. If I open it after I start debugging, it cannot be edited whether it is checked out or not.

Interestingly enough, if I open a read-only file after I start debugging and begin to type in the view to edit it, the file is checked out from source control, but cannot be modified. Additionally, when I stop debugging, I must close the file and reopen it in VS in order to edit it.

Just to clarify, if after I start debugging, I open a view file I already had checked out (not read-only), I cannot edit this file. When I stop debugging, I have to close and re-open the file to be able to edit it.

I have edit and continue turned on, and it works as expected for the controllers and models.

It feels like there is a setting that I am missing somewhere.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: There isn't a setting that differentiates controllers from view files. You should be able to just edit them. In fact, view files are should be even more "editable" than controller files because they get compiled by the asp.net compilation system on demand and do not require edit & continue.

Comment: That's what seems intuitive to me as well. However, when I am running or even paused, and try to edit a view file, it gets checked out, but remains not editable. Very strange.

Comment: Same problema here... and didn't found a solution yet.

Comment: I'm having this problem again in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I've suffering this bug for more than a year. See my question about the problem here: [Edit a view in Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501360/edit-a-view-in-runtime)

This hotfix solve the problem for me.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=40811